# discord.py channel.send function takip error

Tags: python

When I run:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(973939538357522474)
    await channel.send(takip)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    test.start()

async def takip():
    url = ""

    R = requests.get(url)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text, "html5lib")

    Title = Soup.find("h1", {"class": "pr-new-br"}).getText()
    List = Soup.find("div", {"class": "pr-bx-nm with-org-prc"})

    fiyat = List.find("span", {"class": "prc-dsc"}).getText()

    degisenfiyat = float(fiyat.replace(",", ".").replace(" TL", ""))

    if (degisenfiyat <= 200):
        print("Fiyat düştü.")

client.run("")
```

I get:

> A `"<function takip at 0x00000244A7A440D0>"` message in the discord channel

I want to use `channel.send` with the `takip` function. How do I do this?

Comment: You're sending your function to the discord channel not the returned value (non existing for now), you first need to change the `print` by a return in your `takip` then `channel.send(takip())`

Comment: @MariusROBERT please can you send true code here?

Answer (score 1):

`takip` is a function, `takip()` is what your function return
for example if you have this code

```
def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b

print(my_sum)
# This one print the function
# expected result : <function my_sum at 0x7f4dc82b7d30>

print(my_sum(1, 2))
# This one print what my function return (so 3 here)
# expected result : 3
```

In your code, you're sending your function to your discord channel, if you want to send `"Fiyat düştü."` if `(degisenfiyat <= 200)`, you have to edit your code to this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(973939538357522474)
    await channel.send(takip()) # Change here

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    test.start()

def takip():
    url = ""

    R = requests.get(url)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text, "html5lib")

    Title = Soup.find("h1", {"class": "pr-new-br"}).getText()
    List = Soup.find("div", {"class": "pr-bx-nm with-org-prc"})

    fiyat = List.find("span", {"class": "prc-dsc"}).getText()

    degisenfiyat = float(fiyat.replace(",", ".").replace(" TL", ""))

    if (degisenfiyat <= 200):
        return("Fiyat düştü.") # Change here
    else:
        return "degisenfiyat > 200"

client.run("")
```

However if `(degisenfiyat > 200)` this won't return anything so you will be sending `None` to your discord channel, I recommend you to add an `else` statement to return an error or more information (i.e.`error : degisenfiyat > 200`)

Comment: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'takip' was never awaited
  content = str(content) if content is not None else None
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback` I edited and code gave this error

Comment: you probably need to remove `async` for your `takip` function, tell me if it work

Comment: i removed but bot send "<coroutine object takip at 0x000001EC22C6ECE0>" in discord channel.

Comment: and you changed `await channel.send(takip)` to `await channel.send(takip())` ?

Comment: Yes, i changed this

Comment: Did you added a `else` with another `return` ?

Comment: How, can you send all of code?

Comment: Juste edited with the else statement

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the function object. You need to call the function with parenthesis `()`

This line:

```
await channel.send(takip)
```

Should be

```
await channel.send(takip())
```

`takip()` also needs to `return` a value to the caller, not `print()` it to the terminal. Use `return` instead of `print`:

```
if (degisenfiyat <= 200):
    return "Fiyat düştü."
```

---

Consider this example of the function object, vs the returned value:

```py
>>> def f():
...     return "Hello"
... 
>>> f()
'Hello'
>>> f
<function f at 0x103149fc0>
```

---

And finally, you need to remove the `await` from your function definition, as your call does not need to be asynchronous with the bot. This leaves your code at:

```
# ...

@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(973939538357522474)
    # Define x as the function's result before awaiting
    x = takip()
    await channel.send(x)

# ...

def takip():
    url = ""

    R = requests.get(url)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text, "html5lib")

    Title = Soup.find("h1", {"class": "pr-new-br"}).getText()
    List = Soup.find("div", {"class": "pr-bx-nm with-org-prc"})

    fiyat = List.find("span", {"class": "prc-dsc"}).getText()

    degisenfiyat = float(fiyat.replace(",", ".").replace(" TL", ""))

    if (degisenfiyat <= 200):
        return "Fiyat düştü."
    else:
        return f"Error, degisenfiyat > 200. degisenfiyat = {degisenfiyat}"

client.run("")
```

Comment: This is a part of the solution but not the full solution, his `takip` function don't return anything for now so it will send `None` to the discord channel

Comment: Yeah just realised, fixing now

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan i did it and gave error again

Comment: @Frantic What error is it ?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan bot not sending message

Comment: @Frantic, are you sure thats not just because `takip` is returning nothing? try (`print(takip())`) to see if you actualy get a result. Because you will get `None` if your condition of `degisenfiyat <= 200` is not met

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan please send all of code because i cant did it

Comment: @Frantic Check updated code

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan i changed but same, bot isn't sending message